# Swift - Why can I not return an NSNumber or Double data type from this NSDictionary object?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

The second line of the code segment below returns an error unless I change the portion that reads "as NSNumber" to "as String". The value returned in rowData["lngID"] is a numeric value. Can someone please explain this to me?

```
let rowData: NSDictionary = objReport as NSDictionary

let lngReportID = rowData["lngID"] as NSNumber
```

What I'm actually attempting to do here is take a JSON response and load it into an array of objects as follows. Perhaps there is a better way to achieve this. Any suggestions for a better approach is much appreciated. First, the function didReceiveAPIResults returns the results to the app. Then the function loadReportsIntoArray is called.

```
func loadReportsIntoArray(pReports: NSArray) {

    arrayPoints = []

    for (intRow, objReport) in enumerate(pReports) {
        // index is the index within the array
        // participant is the real object contained in the array
        let rowData: NSDictionary = objReport as NSDictionary

        let lngReportID = rowData["lngID"] as NSNumber
        let lngReportTypeID = rowData["lngTypeID"] as NSNumber
        let strOtherTypeName = rowData["strOtherTypeName"] as String
        let strDescription = rowData["strDescription"] as String
        let dtmFirstReport = rowData["dtmFirstReport"] as String
        let dblLat = rowData["dblLat"] as NSNumber
        let dblLong = rowData["dblLong"] as NSNumber
        let strReportedByUsername = rowData["strReportedByUsername"] as String
        let lngReportedByID = rowData["lngReportedBy"] as NSNumber
        let lngCommentCount = rowData["lngCommentCount"] as NSNumber
        let lngNumLikes = rowData["lngNumLikes"] as NSNumber
        let blnUserLikedEvent = rowData["blnUserLikedEvent"] as Bool

        var objReport = Report(plngReportID: lngReportID, plngReportTypeID: lngReportTypeID, pstrOtherTypeName: strOtherTypeName, pstrDescription: strDescription, pdtmFirstReport: dtmFirstReport, pdblLat: dblLat, pdblLong: dblLong, pstrReportedByUsername: strReportedByUsername, plngReportedByID: lngReportedByID, plngCommentCount: lngCommentCount, plngNumLikes: lngNumLikes, pblnUserLikedEvent: blnUserLikedEvent)

        //arrayPoints.append(objReport)
    }

}

func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {
    var success: NSInteger = results["success"] as NSInteger
    if success == 1 {
        var resultsArr = results["geopoints"] as NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.loadReportsIntoArray(resultsArr)
        })
    }
    else {
        // Error occurred
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's a numeric value?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a string representation of that number, for example?

Comment: The value is being returned from a JSON object. It's possible it could be a string representation of a numeric value. Even so, shouldn't it return as a numeric value if the code specifies "as NSNumber"?

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: It just says EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the first line of code that attempts to assign from rowData to lngReportID.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your error using the following code:

```
let objReport = NSDictionary(object: "string", forKey: "lngID")
let rowData: NSDictionary = objReport as NSDictionary

let lngReportID = rowData["lngID"] as NSNumber // Error
```

However, changing the `objReport` to `NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(integer: 0), forKey: "lngID")` solved the problem. Therefore, I think your problem is the object stored for the key `lngID` isn't an `NSNumber`.

For the solution to this you should look at Kumar Nitin's answer to check you've got a number stored, or you could use the code, they both do the same thing pretty much:

```
if let lngID = rowData["lngID"] as? NSNumber {
    //  Do stuff with lngID.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm pretty new to the Swift language so I'm running into some bumps in the road so to speak. I'm about to edit my original post to show what I'm actually attempting to do. Perhaps someone may have a better approach than the one I'm taking.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you don't have NSNumber, however you can use the Obj C's NSNumber if need be.

The above code for NSNumber should be as follows if you are expecting a double or float or int. Add a check to ensure the value is not nil, or else it will crash your app.

```
if let lngReportID = rowData["lngID"] as? Int {
 //Do the task required
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Kumar. I'm pretty new to the Swift language so I'm running into some bumps in the road so to speak. I'm about to edit my original post to show what I'm actually attempting to do. Perhaps someone may have a better approach than the one I'm taking.